# Speed up react-native "npm install" step to solve dependancy?

Tags: react-native

I can see whenever we create a new react-native project using `react-native init myProject` then `npm install` process takes a lot of time in solving dependancies. While, I know `yarn` also speed things up for project building. But is there anyway, we could avoid those repeated downloads for every react-native project from yarn and npm install to speed things up?

Please give your thoughts or suggestion on it.

Comment: I suppose you could manually copy and paste the contents of node_modules between projects. But how much of an issue is this, really? Are you creating hundreds of new projects?

Comment: What you want to do isn't a good thing, because you aren't getting the newest versions of npm packages

Comment: Your point is it npm install install and updates all packages every time for a react-native app build?